# Explanation for near sdk promise

Tags: nearprotocol

https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.11.0/near_sdk/struct.Promise.html

In [cross contract call example](https://github.com/near-examples/rust-high-level-cross-contract/blob/master/src/lib.rs)

It contains following promise

```
impl CrossContract {
    pub fn deploy_status_message(&self, account_id: String, amount: u64) {
        Promise::new(account_id)
            .create_account()
            .transfer(amount as u128)
            .add_full_access_key(env::signer_account_pk())
            .deploy_contract(
                include_bytes!("../status-message-contract/status_message.wasm").to_vec(),
            );
    }
```

This is the near command for calling deploy_status_message

```
near call cross_contract deploy_status_message '{"account_id": "status_message", "amount":1000000000000000}' --accountId mainaccount
```

Can you please explain this Promise chain:

1) It takes argument `status_message` as `account_id`, `create_account` should create an account `status_message`,
but

`near state status_message`

gives error

```
account status_message does not exist while viewing
```

2) Also what should

```
include_bytes!(...)
```

contain, which string?

3) What transfer function do here? Does it takes 1000000000000000 from `mainaccount` and deposit it in `status_message` account?

4) `add_full_access_key` Adds full access key to the which account? `status_message`? What is the need for `env::signer_account_pk()` as argument?

Answer (score 1):

1 It does. <strike>You probably have the wrong env var and therefore end up querying a different network.</strike>
UPD: The example is broken. Fix here https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/pull/193.

2 include_bytes is a built-in rust macro that is not related to near-sdk-rs. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/macro.include_bytes.html

3 Not sure what is `mainaccount`, but it transfers 1000000000000000 from the current account balance of the contract account to the status_message account. Note that the current account balance includes the attached deposit as well.

4 Yes it adds to the `status_message` account. To add a key you need to specify the key that you are adding and `env::signer_account_pk()` gives you a key.

Comment: My environment variables are correct, but still, near state status_message gives an error. Also, will the smart contract fetch the wasm file from local computer and upload it to contract, any directory I run the command it doesn't give any error.

Comment: The issue is that you didn't attach any tokens with your call so it failed when trying to transfer tokens. The reason why you can run it from any directory is that the inclusion is done at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: @user1566713 sorry for the incorrect answer. The example is indeed broken and the pr to fix it is here https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/pull/193